# $form array in views-exposed-form.tpl.php has #printed set to true?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I'm not doing anything to it in any other functions, but every #printed is set to TRUE when it reaches the .tpl. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1):

#printed is set by drupal_render, so if the actual form element is rendering into a string the $form has #printed, try it out on any other drupal form theming.